# BrowserLink not working in Blazor WASM Project

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

BrowserLink has stopped working in one of my Blazor WASM projects (the other work ok so this is a project issue).

On the browser console I occasionally see I'm getting an ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED issue trying to connect to browserlink/negotiate.

On VS I can see that the browser link dashboard says that I am connected, but when I change a razor.css file the change is not sync'd with the browser.

I have re-installed VS (its now on the latest version) and also deleted the .vs folder in the project directory, but that didn't work.

Any ideas?

- Edit - It's the VS to Browser CSS update that's stopped working - as Lonespawn comments Hot Reload is pretty useless generally

Comment: I gave up on hot reload a long time ago. It stops working pretty quickly once your project becomes much more than the standard template.

Comment: @LoneSpawn, I agree with you on Hot Reload for anything but a basic project, but the CSS update part of things is so useful that I'd really rather not lose it.

Comment: Same experience.

Comment: I should add, Hot Reload and the instant CSS update is amazing and a massive time saver when it works. I am looking forward to the issues with it being resolved. Maybe someone has a temporary fix.